# Trying to print a method using another method

Tags: java, methods, void, println

Not sure where I'm going wrong with this. I've asked someone in my class and they said there should be an argument with "toonRijSterren". when I do this I just get more errors, could someone have a look and tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int aantal = 0;
    toonRijSterren(aantal);
    toonSterrenVierkant(aantal);
}

public static void toonRijSterren(int mpAantal) {
    while (mpAantal < 6) {
        System.out.print(" * ");
        mpAantal++;
    }
}

public static void toonSterrenVierkant(int mpAantal) {
    for (int mpAatal = 0; mpAantal < 6; mpAantal++) {
        System.out.println(toonRijSterren());
    }
}
```

ther error line is in the brackets of the last toonRijSterren());

Comment: "I just get more errors" - we don' know what errors. Would you edit the question and add them? Also, add the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `toonRijSterren` is `void` method which means it does not return any value and therefore you can not put it inside `System.out.println()` or you can not assign it to some variable.
2. `toonRijSterren` expects an `int` argument which you have missed while calling it.

Given below is an example of how you should call `toonRijSterren`:

```
public static void toonSterrenVierkant(int mpAantal) {
    for (int mpAatal = 0; mpAatal < 6; mpAatal++) {
        toonRijSterren(mpAantal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the argument when you call your method.

Try this:

```
System.out.println(toonRijSterren(mpAatal));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but when i do that i keep getting error statements saying add braces to for, and when i correct that it tells me to get rid of them again :/

Comment: Like @yon264 says, you are not returning an integer value when you call your method `toonRijSterren(mpAantal)`. 

In your `toonSterrenVierkant() ` method, 
change the `System.out.println(toonRijSterren(mpAatal));` to 
`toonRijSterren(mpAatal);`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parameter in your toonSterrenVierkant() function where you calling toonRijSterren.

Here is the corrected version of your code:

```
public static void toonSterrenVierkant(int mpAantal) { 
  for (; mpAantal < 6; mpAantal++) { 
    toonRijSterren(mpAatal); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: When i do that i keep getting error statements saying add braces to for, and when i correct that it tells me to get rid of them again :/

Comment: It seems you have a general problem with the braces in your class. Check if there is an closing brace for every opening and check if they are in the right places

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function `toonRijSterren` takes an `int` type parameter (according to its declaration), so you need to pass to it another argument. For example: 
`toonRijSterren(mpAantal)`

Second, the function `toonRijSterren` returns `void`. That means, it just does an operation (in this case, printing) without returning anything. What you're trying to do is to use its return value (which doesn't exist) as an argument to `System.out.println`, which causes an error (because `println` expects an argument of some type). 
You could achieve what I think you're trying to do with the line:
`toonRijSterren(mpAantal);`. 
The function itself prints the values, so the `println` here is unnecessary and causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

As your methed `toonSterrenVierkant(int mpAantal)` has a `int` parameter, you must pass an `int` value as an argument in the last `toonRijSterren()`. For example, replace the line `System.out.println(toonRijSterren());` with `System.out.println(toonRijSterren(1));`